# ¿Como puedo colocar un elemento en la posición (x,y) en un layout en Android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Quiero hacer lo siguiente en Android, colocar la imagen de fondo, y encima un elemento (puede ser botón, imagen, u otro) pero en la posición `(x,y)` y que el eje de coordenadas esté en la esquina inferior izquierda como muestra la imagen.

Lo intente con el elemento `Button`, lo cree en el código y luego agrego la posición con la función `setX(Float)` y `setY(Float)` pero no se como hacer para que la posición del contenedor padre este en la esquina inferior izquierda.

Además, ¿Se puede trabajar con "`AnchorPoint`" para cambiar el punto del eje de coordenadas en Android, en los Layout de Android?

La idea es hacerlo con código no con XML, porque con XML lo hace solo Android Studio.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo el Layout así:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="miaum_es.v1.miaum.cl.miaum_es.Home">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/scene"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/boton"/>
    </FrameLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Después en mi Activity:

En el método `onCreate`, defino la escena y el click de un botón:

```
private FrameLayout scene;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);

    scene = (FrameLayout)findViewById(R.id.scene);
    scene.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

    Button btnSum =(Button)findViewById(R.id.boton);
    btnSum.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            ImageView fondo = getImageView(R.drawable.fondon,0,0);
            ImageView santa = getImageView(R.drawable.santa,150,100);

            scene.addView(fondo);
            scene.addView(santa);

        }
    });
}
```

Y ejecuta la siguiente función:

```
public ImageView getImageView(int id_image, float x, float y)
{
    ImageView image = new ImageView(this);
    image.setLayoutParams(
            new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                    WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT
            )
    );
    image.setImageResource(id_image);
    image.setX(x);
    image.setY(y);
    return image;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Primero que todo, vamos a ir por partes.

```
> 1.- No has comentado tú código, por lo que te responderé con ejemplos propios
> 2.- Me basaré en tu imagen. Asumiendo que Santa es un ImageView y esta adentro de un LinearLayout.
```

Tú código actual debe estar así:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/RootLayout">

    <!-- Imagen de fondo -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@mipmap/background">

        <!-- Imagen de Santa-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/santa" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Para conseguir lo que pides debemos cambiar el gravity (a bottom) del LinearLayout que contiene al santa. Y ahora vamos a definir un layout_marginBottom y layout_marginLeft en la imageView. Quedándonos lo siguiente:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    style="@style/RootLayout">

    <!-- Imagen de fondo -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:background="@mipmap/background">

        <!-- Imagen de Santa-->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@mipmap/santa"
            android:layout_marginLeft="50pt"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50pt" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Saludos

Comment: si no agrego su codigo, pidele al op que lo agregue!

Comment: para usar ese tipo de medidas, puedes usar relativelayout

Comment: No tengo código, la idea  es hacer el botón o imagen dinámico no con XML. La otra duda es si quiero cambiar en eje de referencia se puede?

Comment: el eje X e Y, se logra con un margin, tal como lo implemente en el ejemplo. No pidas ahora que no sea en el xml, eso se hace desde el comienzo...

Comment: No decía explicito, pero lo decía en la duda lee:  `Lo intente con el elemento Button, lo cree en el código y luego agrego la posición con la función... `